# Messenger via AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I have a website and and iOS app which uses Amazon Cognito for login and security purposes. Now I need a messenger with which only Authenticated Cognito User are able to communicate. I only need 1on1 conversations (no group chats etc.) and I need to save the history for each conversation. I thought about using SNS or SQS but I am really not sure if that is a good idea...

Does someone have any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon APIGateway, Amazon Lambda, Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon SNS and IOT Websockets to implement the chat application.

- Use APIGateway and Lambda to implement receiving messages and store the chat messages in DynamoDB.
- From Lambda also publish the message to IOT websocket that is listened by browser client.
- To publish messages to mobile client trigger SNS topic to push notifications from Lambda.

For more details refer the blog article [Receiving AWS IoT messages in your browser using websockets](https://medium.com/@jparreira/receiving-aws-iot-messages-in-your-browser-using-websockets-9b87f28c2357).

Comment: Thank you. DynamoDb sounds like a good idea to store the messages.
But I somehow need to secure the specific entries, so just the two Cognito-Users who are communicating have access to it...

To allow access to a single Identity I simply use an condition like this:

 "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {"dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
          


But how can I give acces to an additional identity?

Comment: You can't give two identities at policy level. Instead, do the authorization at API Gateway Custom Authorizer(Preferred) or at integration Lambda.

Comment: API Gateway Authorizer seems good... is there any way to do this with EC2? Currently I am doing everything with  EC2 Nodejs or is Lambda a must have?

Comment: No. You need to write a Lambda for Custom Authorizer.